Can two instances of Eclipse/PyDev work off of the same Python source code?
I need to run two instances of Eclipse/PyDev on the same machine that operate on the same source code. The situation is this. Two Python applications use the same common underlying modules in Python source. These two applications communicate with each other via IPC. I want to test these two interacting applications by running them on the same machine, each accessing the same source code modules and each running in a different instantiation of Eclipse/PyDev. Is this going to cause a problem when, for example, I set breakpoints in the common modules using one instantiation? Will this confuse the second instantiation?
I guess the potential problem would arise if Eclipse/PyDev breakpoints somehow modify the common module source code in some way.

You should be able to start both debug sessions on same eclipse instance. Each one will maintain its own stack.

Just to clarify, I am using local debugging (the source code is on the same machine and runs in the same process as Eclipse/PyDev), not remote debugging.
